# Honeywell EDA51 - Scan barcode from Xamarin Forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, barcode, honeywell

I am working on Xamarin Forms app that should be deployed on Honeywell EDA51.
I never used something like this (honeywell eda51) and not really sure how to scan barcode with it.
Do I need some extra Nuget packages or something else to install?
Want to have two ways
On certain page, when you scan barcode it should be written in text field (First some preprocessing) and second functionality should be after click on certain button you should scan multiple barcodes and store them in list.
If I knew how to register scanner input and use it in app I think that I would be able to do both things

Comment: I suggest you read the manual for the device and research any APIs provided by the manufacturer.  Generally, devices with hardware scanners are configured to act as keyboards, where the scan data just appears to the app as keyboard input.  If you want other functionality, you need to find out what options the device supports.

Comment: It seems that you can try to use the zxing nuget package.

Comment: Actually it looks like I don't need any API, as @Jason said it recognize it as keyboard input, but only problem that I have is that is somehow limited to 12 characters only (per scan, It can concatenate multiple barcode on same entry field but in one scan 12 is maximum length).
Barcodes that I need to scan are going to be 13 or 14 in length

Comment: It looks like it was mistake in barcode that I scanned, it works fine now

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to use the built-in scanner in any way other than keyboard mode? The demo app built in the one I have provides info about the type of barcode scanned, so it seems its not capturing the data through keyboard mode?

The Honeywell documentation is severely lacking for how to do anything with these devices.

Answer (score 0):

Honeywell provides some SDKs for Xamarin.
You can go to https://hsmftp.honeywell.com/en and find them in the Software -> Software and Tools -> Developer Library -> SDKs for Xamarin.
You may want to try the Honeywell-Xamarin-Scanning-SDK-v1.35.00.0044.zip package. It contains a short documentation and a NuGet package.

However, you need to register and use the Honeywell Dowlnoad Manager (can be found on the same place) to download the package.

[Honeywell Download page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpZ4y.png)